# how do i increase video recording fps rate in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

i am facing problem while saving video frames(images) on disk . it return me the low frame/sec like 8fps , 10fps, 12fps, 15fps . if i play the  iphone camera app and record the video then i get  29fps, 30fps, so i want my app to calculate the same fps as iphone camera app do

```
- (void) blCameraControllerDidCaptureSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
  if(shouldSaveVideoToGallery)
    {
        [analysisQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
            //        CMTime t=CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
            CMTime t=CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
            float time=CMTimeGetSeconds(t);//t.value;
            if(initialBufferTime==-1)
            {
                initialBufferTime=time;
            }

            time=time-initialBufferTime;


            UIImage *analysisImage=[self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
           // [analysisImageA addObject:analysisImage];

            CMSampleBufferInvalidate(sampleBuffer);
            CFRelease(sampleBuffer);

            NSString *videoName=[[currentVideoPath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];

             NSString *  analysisImagePath=[[[OrbisMediaGallery sharedGallery] getMediaGalleryFolderPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_analysisScreen%d.jpg", videoName, (int)(analysisScreens.count+1)]];
            [imagePathA addObject:analysisImagePath];


            NSData *imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(analysisImage, 0.5);
            [imageData writeToFile:analysisImagePath atomically:NO];

            [analysisQueue saveFrameOnDisk:analysisImage andImgPath:analysisImagePath];

            NSDictionary *d=@{@"analysisScreenPath": analysisImagePath, @"analysisScreenTime": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:time]};
            NSLog(@"_analysisScreen: %@", d);
            [analysisScreens addObject:d];

            NSLog(@"isRecording:%@, analysisQueue.operationCount:%@", @(isRecording), @(analysisQueue.operationCount));
            if(analysisQueue.operationCount<=1)
                isDoneGeneratingFrames=YES;
            if(!isRecording && analysisQueue.operationCount<=1)
            {

             //   [self saveImageOnDisk];
                [self saveFramesOfVideo:currentVideoPath startTime:[d objectForKey:@"analysisScreenTime"]];
                // [[OrbisMediaGallery sharedGallery] saveAnalysisImages:analysisScreens forVideoAtPath:currentVideoPath];
}
}];
    }
    else
    {
        isDoneGeneratingFrames=YES;
    }



}
```

it is the delegate method it call everytime while  video is recording. actually i am facing problem at these line

```
NSData *imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(analysisImage, 0.5);
[imageData writeToFile:analysisImagePath atomically:NO];
```

when i comment these lines then it will return the greater frame rate exactly like iphone camera app. but commenting these two lines the problem arise here is i am not able to stop the video and see it frame wise and please don't tell me to put these lines into background thread or gcd . i had tried putting it on background thread . but  fps rate did not change .

Comment: So you are saying your code is too slow and you want to know how to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Posting comment as answer due to space restriction.

Understand what's happening here. You're taking raw camera data which is 4 bytes per pixel (in rgba) multiplied by your resolution (Height x Width of camera resolution) for each frame and passing it around in memory before trying writing it to disk. Each frame will be several MB in size, and you want to do this 30 times (or more) per second? That's not going to happen, regardless of the fact that you'll run out of space very quickly.

Essentially, your frame rate is being dropped because the delegate is unable to process the incoming packets. I believe (if memory serves me well) the docs even warn about keeping the processing to a minimum in the callback.

What's unclear is your objective. One way to bring the frame rate back up is to move the image processing to a shallow queue, this will have the effect of dropping the processing blocks once the queue reaches it's limit (which you set at creation time). Understand that this simply moves the bottleneck. Another approach is to set the camera capture to a much lower resolution. However, i suspect neither of these will satisfy your need. What you need to do is re-engineer this whole process.

Again without understanding your objective, it's impossible to recommend a good solution, i.e. are you simply saving these frames as images because it's the simplest way to display a given frame when the user pauses the video, or do you really need to retain all these images?

Bottom line, this won't work, if you elaborate on your needs, perhaps a solution can be found that will satisfy your requirements.